# Base64-encoded binary string, txt to PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf, base64

I am trying to download PDF's via an API where I recieve the data as Base64-encoded binary in JSON format.
Is there a way to convert that to a pdf using R?

My approach is the following but that generated "PDF" can't be read properly by a PDF reader.
By looking at it in Notepad it also looks like it is missing something like additional metadata?, as it should create the following [PDF](https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/2021/downloads/RESTSDK/RESTAPIs/output.pdf)

```
file <- fromJSON("data.txt")
decoded <- base64_dec(file$data)
save(decoded, "file.pdf")
```

File: [data.txt](https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/downloads/RESTSDK/RESTAPIs/data.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `writeBin` to write out the binary raw data to a file

```
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON("data.txt")
raw <- openssl::base64_decode(data$data)
writeBin(raw, "output.pdf")
```